# Jquery Hide parent label if span contains 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few labels like the following:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" class="brand custom-control-input filters filter_level_100" data-filter-level="100" data-filter-type="checkbox" name="checkbox0" id="checkbox0" value="282">
            <span class="custom-control-label"> BMW<span class="label label-secondary float-right brand_counts" id="brand_counts_BMW">0</span> </span> </label>
```

Now i want to hide the label if the span contains "0"!
The following only hide the span.

```
$(".brand_counts").filter(function(){
           $(this).text().trim() === "0";
        }).hide();
```

But how can i hide the parent label?
Thank you

Comment: select the parent before you call hide

Comment: You want to hide the "label" or the "span.custom-control-label" or "span.label"?

Comment: the whole label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are missing return inside the filter. Without that you will never find an element. Second, you need to look up the tree to the label so you have to use closest.

```js
$(".brand_counts").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === "0"; // you missed return here
}).closest('label').hide(); // select the grandparent with closest
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="brand custom-control-input filters filter_level_100" data-filter-level="100" data-filter-type="checkbox" name="checkbox0" id="checkbox0" value="282">
  <span class="custom-control-label"> BMW<span class="label label-secondary float-right brand_counts" id="brand_counts_BMW">0</span> </span> 
</label>
```